# XSLT equation using SP list fields

Tags: sharepoint, xpath, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a SP Dataview that I have converted to XSLT, so that I could add a header displaying a percentage (Complete). 
Before I converted the dvwp to xslt, I added two count headers- one on Complete, and another on LastName. They worked wonderfully- showing me the # of records and the # of records with a value in the complete field.  However, when I converted the dv to xslt I realized that I lost my headers :( 
So, I am adding them back in using xslt. Currently the XPath code for the equation that I have is `<xsl:value-of select="count($Rows) div count($Rows)" />`.
How do I get the total # of Yes values that are in my Complete field?

**UPDATE1:**
Found this http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=534 and tried it, however causes the following error- **Failed setting processor stylesheet: 0x80004005: Argument 1 must return a node-set. -->count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row='Y')<--**

**UPDATE2:**
Complete is the name of a field w/i my XSLT dataset. The return type is either Y or blank. For grins I tried `<xsl:value-of select="count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete eq 'Y']) div count($Rows)" />` however I recieved the following error- **Failed setting processor stylesheet: 0x80004005: Expected token ']' found 'NAME'.count((/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete -->eq <--'Y']) div count($Rows)** Am starting to think that there may be a problem w/ 'eq'.... Referencing my XML operators...

**UPDATE3:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete = 'Y']) div count($Rows)" />
```

Okay so it still says 0, but I think the reason why it's not showing the correct answer is b/c it is expecting to show an integer, and obviously the value being returned from the equation is going to be a decimal... Have been fiddling with the equation in XPath... here's what I've tried-

```
count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete = 'Y']) div count($Rows)*100
(count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete = 'Y']) div count($Rows))*100
100(count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete = 'Y']) div count($Rows))
```

**UPDATE4:**
So I know my previous thought that the correct number not showing b/c it was a float is not correct, as all numbers in XPath and XSLT 1.0 are floats. [Reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=W6SpffnfEPoC&pg=PA552&lpg=PA552&dq=xpath+1.0+floating+point+numbers&source=bl&ots=DQPqnQM-sD&sig=fngHN2CsCXd8piLyNuPXMLfINF0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_xsUT6nDOOXz0gGB_IipAw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=xpath%201.0%20floating%20point%20numbers&f=false)

**UPDATE5:**
Upon further investigation, I have found that the problem lies with the `count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@Complete = 'Y'])` part of my equation, as this is returning 0 instead of a value. [i know i have at least 3 'Y' vals in my Complete col]

**UPDATE6**:

```
<records*>
<record*>
  <last_name></last_name>
  <first_name></first_name>
  <mi></mi>
  <office_symbol></office_symbol>
  <geo_location></geo_location>
  <complete></complete>
  <date_complete></date_complete>
  <date_expires></date_expires>
  <email></email>
  <supervisor></supervior>
</record*>
</records*>
```

*i don't know what these nodes are called as my data is coming from a database and not an xml file, i just made up record/records

**UPDATE7**
Going back to my original question. I am still trying to find out the XPath equation to display the number of parents (record in the XML i posted above) where the complete node = Y.

**UPDATE8**
Ok. So I have edited and tested using http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_value-of. Working XSLT to count the # of Complete = Y is `<xsl:value-of select="count(catalog/cd [complete = 'Y'])" />` so theen I put EXACTLY what works on W3schools into my SP Dataview and I get nothing... just an empty space. Why doesn't the code work in my SPDV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "Complete" field is an element:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/xpath/to/complete/field/element[string(.) eq 'Yes])"/>
```

If your complete field is an attribute of an element:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="count(/xpath/to/parent/element[@complete eq 'Yes'])"/>
```

Without knowing the structure of your XML I can't provide the specific XPATH required -- the predicate "[]" is what selects only the "Yes" values

Comment: It seems to me that you are using XPath 2.0 in this answer. However, the XSLT processor used by Sharepoint is (AFAIK) an XSLT 1.0 one and doesn't support XPath 2.0.